# add uicomponent inside a sprite

Tags: apache-flex

i want to add UIComponent inside a spite. here is the code:

```
private function make() : void {
    var circle : Sprite = new Sprite();
    circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.2);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
    var button : Button = new Button();
    button.label = "testing...";
    var wrapper : UIComponent = new UIComponent();

    circle.addChild( button );
    wrapper.addChild( circle );
    addChild( wrapper );
}
```

the problem is that button is added, but is not displayed. if i do reversed - add sprite to uicomponent - everything works fine, but this way it doesn't work. i tried to use invalidate functions for button etc... even tried making "circle" as UIMovieClip, but no luck - button is still invisible. also if i simply do "addChild( button );" - it is shown, what the... please help, what i am doing wrong? how can i add a button inside a sprite?

Comment: The real question is why do you want to add a UIcomponent to sprite?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of class inheritances and how to implement them.

Comment: Just want to let you know I took your code out of the function imported the respective classes and run it in a blank fla on frame 1 and it works. I get a button with a quarter circle drawn on it in the upper left corner as it should be. So my guess is you are either covering over the button or not positioning it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't. What you CAN do is instead of using Sprite, you use UIComponent for your circle.

The reason for this is that UIComponent has A LOT of code that changes how it behaves, including how to add and layout children.  You could essentially take the same code to a Sprite since UIComponent does extend it, however that would be VERY redundant.  This works great for me:

```
private function make() : void {
    var circle : UIComponent= new UIComponent();
    circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.2);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
    var button : Button = new Button();
    button.label = "testing...";
    var wrapper : UIComponent = new UIComponent();

    circle.addChild( button );
    wrapper.addChild( circle );
    addChild( wrapper );
}
```

Comment: what i actually want to do is to load an external swf, then move some movieclip in it and add a button to it. this is a requirement. for now i can load and move, but when i try to add a button - nothing happens... i can see only that numChildren property is incremented and that's all. how can i initialize or display that dynamically created button?

Comment: You won't be able to with a Flex button.  You'd be better off just creation your own button using Movieclip or you know, actually modify the swf you're loading.  Maybe just place the button above the movieclip?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in order to use Sprite the way you are trying to do it, you would have to extend Sprite and implement IUIComponent.

Taken from the Flex 3 Language Reference:

> Note: While the child argument to the
>   method is specified as of type
>   DisplayObject, the argument must
>   implement the IUIComponent interface
>   to be added as a child of a container.
>   All Flex components implement this
>   interface.

Sprite does not implement IUIComponent, so you are experiencing a pretty typical issue. UIComponent's don't typically have speed issues when compared to Sprites, so I would recommend just drawing on your UIComponent.

As stated before, you /could/ extend Sprite to implement IUIComponent, but it's a pain.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is wrong. UIcomponents inherit from sprite class. Sprite class is the base class for all visual componets. UIcomponent class inherits Sprite and adds user functionality like mouse clicks.

Comment: yes, that's wrong. :-) well, i've already tried to extend the sprite into some UISprite which would implement IUIComponent, but still nothing. the button is not displayed. also i've found via the debugger that the button has "initialized" property set to "false". well, i tried to call "button.initialize()", also i tried to set: button.explicitWidth = button.explicitHeight = 100; but still no luck... the same goes if the "circle" is UIMovieClip... maybe i need to call some additional special method for the button?

Comment: what i actually want to do is to load an external swf, then move some movieclip in it and add a button to it. this is a requirement. for now i can load and move, but when i try to add a button - nothing happens... i can see only that numChildren property is incremented and that's all. how can i initialize or display that dynamically created button?

Comment: Opps sorry said it backwards for some reason don't know what i was thinking. Sprite inherits from UIComponent.

Comment: er, no it doesn't.  What andrew said was 100% right. It goes UIComponent => FlexSprite => Sprite. Look it up [in the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html).